# "Snapping" shut/quickly closing gates

Tags: linkage

Suppose you have a set of two gates like so:
[image: 1]

Where you only want one of the gates to be in the "open" (non-blocking") position at any given time, this being the other possible state:
[image]

How could you go about ensuring that only one of these is open at any given time? (or that they are only both open for a very short duration).

My initial thought was to create a linkage between them, with a middle pivot, but this would not provide a rapid close. Like so (Where the red is a static pin that doesn't move):
[image]

The best way of converting this mechanism to be what i desire would be to use the end of the linkage in a mechanism similar to [what a switch uses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0GGy.png), but that would take up way too much space.

Additionally, it would be ideal if the mechanism could be made with minimal non-3D printed parts (save for something like a generic spring). The closest design I've come across was [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaRBadgcUlU) design, where the green linkage is snapping between two positions, but I wouldn't even know where to start with using that in the above needed way.

Comment: The close with your lever will be as rapid as the open, so make the open faster.

Comment: With your idea, both gates will be partially open as one gate moves from either the open position to the close position, or vice versa. Do you want this to happen or would you prefer both gates to be shut & then to open either as need be?

Comment: What about two butterfly valves out of phase with one another?  As one valve shuts, the other opens.